# Making a matrix for a smuge/wobble effet ( see pictures ) in Android

Tags: java, android, matrix

***THANKS Torious, got it:***

```
    private void smudge() {


        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT*2; i += 2) {

            float xOriginal = matrixOriganal[i+0];
            float yOriginal = matrixOriganal[i+1];

            float distX = Math.abs(pointX-xOriginal);
            float distY = Math.abs(pointY-yOriginal);

            float dist = FloatMath.sqrt( distX*distX + distY*distY );

            float coof = ( bubbleSize - dist ) / bubbleSize;

        float oc = (float) -Math.sin(coof * 2*Math.PI) * 0.15f ;

            if ( dist < bubbleSize )
            {
            matrixVertsMoved[i+0] = xOriginal + smudgeAmount * (coof+oc);
            matrixVertsMoved[i+1] = yOriginal;
            }
            else
            {
            matrixVertsMoved[i+0] = xOriginal;
            matrixVertsMoved[i+1] = yOriginal;
            }


        }

        invalidate();
    }
```

---

**old:**
Right now I have this code that I made based on the api sample that comes with the SDK.

```
public class main extends Activity {

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout ll01 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

        SampleView sv = new SampleView(this);
        ll01.addView(sv);
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    private static class SampleView extends View {
        static int WIDTH = 8; // sections
        static int HEIGHT = 8;
        static int COUNT = (WIDTH + 1) * (HEIGHT + 1); // total verts count

        Bitmap mBitmap; // declaring a bitmap
        float[] matrixVertsMoved = new float[COUNT*2]; // declaring an array with double amount of vert count, one for x and one for y
        float[] matrixOriganal = new float[COUNT*2];

        float clickX;
        float clickY;

        static void setXY(float[] array, int index, float x, float y) {
            array[index*2 + 0] = x;
            array[index*2 + 1] = y;
        }

        ///

        public SampleView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);

            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.w);


            // construct our mesh
            int index = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y <= HEIGHT; y++) {
                float fy = mBitmap.getHeight() * y / HEIGHT;

                for (int x = 0; x <= WIDTH; x++) {
                    float fx = mBitmap.getWidth() * x / WIDTH;
                    setXY(matrixVertsMoved, index, fx, fy);
                    setXY(matrixOriganal, index, fx, fy);
                    index += 1;
                }

            }

        }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


            canvas.drawBitmapMesh(mBitmap, WIDTH, HEIGHT, matrixVertsMoved, 0,  null, 0, null);

            Paint p1 = new Paint();
            p1.setColor(0x660000FF);

            Paint p2 = new Paint();
            p2.setColor(0x99FF0000);

            Paint p3 = new Paint();
            p3.setColor(0xFFFFFB00);

            for (int i = 0; i < COUNT*2; i += 2) {
                float x = matrixOriganal[i+0];
                float y = matrixOriganal[i+1];
                canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 4, p1);

                float x1 = matrixOriganal[i+0];
                float y1 = matrixOriganal[i+1];
                float x2 = matrixVertsMoved[i+0];
                float y2 = matrixVertsMoved[i+1];
                canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, p1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < COUNT*2; i += 2) {
                float x = matrixVertsMoved[i+0];
                float y = matrixVertsMoved[i+1];
                canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 4, p2);
            }

            canvas.drawCircle(clickX, clickY, 6, p3);


        }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

        private void smudge() {


            for (int i = 0; i < COUNT*2; i += 2) {

                float xOriginal = matrixOriganal[i+0];
                float yOriginal = matrixOriganal[i+1];

                float dist_click_to_origin_x = clickX - xOriginal; // distance from current vertex in the original matrix to the place clicked.
                float dist_click_to_origin_y = clickY - yOriginal;

                float kv_kat = dist_click_to_origin_x*dist_click_to_origin_x + dist_click_to_origin_y*dist_click_to_origin_y;

                float pull = ( 1000000 / kv_kat / FloatMath.sqrt(kv_kat) );

                if (pull >= 1) {
                    matrixVertsMoved[i+0] = clickX;
                    matrixVertsMoved[i+1] = clickY;
                } else {
                    matrixVertsMoved[i+0] = xOriginal + dist_click_to_origin_x * pull;
                    matrixVertsMoved[i+1] = yOriginal + dist_click_to_origin_y * pull;
                }

            }


        }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

                clickX = event.getX();
                clickY = event.getY(); 
                smudge(); // change the matrix.
                invalidate(); // calls a redraw on the canvas.

            return true;
        }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    }
```

The important this is the wrap function at the end. Here's what it produces.

// blue dots are the vertexes of the original matrix, while the red ones show how they moved from the click ( yellow dot ).

[image]

Yet that I need is it not to pinch in a vertex, but to sort of smudge it, like this.

[image]

For example, this smudge function could take in pixel or vertex coordinates from where to start the smudge, x and y offset and strength of the smudge, i.e. how hard should be the surrounding vertexes be affected.

Any ideas how to do that?

**edit: basically I'm trying to make something similar to http://www.andwobble.com/**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got a (Flash) demo working that looks to be what you need.

*I haven't transformed a textured mesh, but only vertices, so it's hard to verify if the effect is exactly as intended, but it looks to be a step in the right direction.*

Anyway, here is the code; it's in AS3 but I doubt it'll be hard to understand.

Some notes:

- `CENTER` in the code below would be the starting point of the smudge operation, as you describe it above. The `controlPoint` would be the end point.
- I'm using `Vector3D`, but only using its 2D coordinates.
- `CENTER`, `controlPoint` and the input `vertex` are treated as if in the same coordinate system. You could instead pre-process `CENTER` to be relative to your mesh's local coordinate system. Then you could strip the transforms to/from the relative/local coordinate system that are in the code below.
- The logistic function is used for the transition from the edge of the circle of influence with no influence, to full influence. You could probably use several other functions for similar effect.
- I think using an additional, second "pull to control point" operation with a smaller strength and less steep transition would make the effect better; right now all vertices that are fully transitioned to (close to) 100% influence move towards the control point a bit too much in unison, I feel.

Try it out and let me know if you have trouble understanding the AS3 code.

```
    private function log(t:Number):Number {
        return 1 / (1 + Math.pow(Math.E, -t));
    }

    private function transformVertex(vertex:Vector3D, controlPoint:Vector3D):Vector3D {

        // get control point relative to center of influence
        // (this could actually be calculated in pre-processing, as
        // it doesn't change between vertices)
        var controlPointRel:Vector3D = controlPoint.subtract(CENTER);

        // get vertex relative to center of influence
        var rel:Vector3D = vertex.subtract(CENTER);

        // get distance of vertex from center
        var dst:Number = rel.length / RADIUS;
        if (dst > 1) return vertex; // vertex outside circle of influence


        // PULL TO CONTROL POINT

        // tScale controls the steepness of the transition from the
        // edge of the circle. 1 = logistic transition, >1 = steeper
        var tScale:Number = 1.7;
        var t:Number = (1 - dst) * 12 * tScale - 6; // [-6, 6]
        t = log(t);

        controlPointRel = controlPointRel.clone();
        controlPointRel.scaleBy(t);
        // ALTERNATIVE, try this too:
        // controlPointRel.scaleBy(t * (1 - dst));

        rel = rel.add(controlPointRel);

        // relative to absolute
        return rel.add(CENTER);

    }
```